# Why are not all of the communities shown in hat display?

Tags: discussion, design, winter-bash-2020

I was looking at my hats, and because I am a member of a bunch of SE sites, which I visit regularly, I earned the Social Distancing Main hat on 9 of them. But my profile will only show 7 of the sites where I earned the hat:
[image]

There is enough space to show the other site icons under the first row, so why does it say 'and 2 other sites' instead of just showing the sites? It just seems odd that it shows text and not the sites themselves.

Comment: A cleaner look?  Eventually, if you earn enough hats, it's going to start pushing down there.  I only need four more...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, 9 communities may not be a problem, but there 176 different Stack Exchange sites, and there *are* users who joined them all. How would 176, or say just 30 sites, look all cluttered up on that small area? Not too professional, I imagine...

[image]

Yep. *(I haven't really earned the badge on every site, of course.)*

Comment: How did you make that image if you didn't earn the badge on all those sites?

Comment: @user1271772 Grueling paint work ;)

Comment: Looks pretty flawless to me. I see no columns or rows that are not straight!